# Strange Behavior Saving to PDF in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios8

I've been using the code below to save a specified `UIScrollView` as a .pdf file.

```
+ (NSString *) saveAsPDF:(UIScrollView *)view withName:(NSString *)filename
{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfPathWithFileName = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

    // Generate PDF
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfPathWithFileName, CGRectZero, nil);
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, view.contentSize.width, view.contentSize.height), nil);

        // My Draw View
        {
            NSArray *subviews = [view subviews];
            UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.contentSize.width, view.contentSize.height)];

            for (UIView *viewLoop in subviews)
            {
                [contentView addSubview:viewLoop];
            }

            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            [contentView setBackgroundColor:[self colorForBlueBackground]];
            [contentView.layer renderInContext:context];

            for (UIView *viewLoop in [contentView subviews])
            {
                [viewLoop removeFromSuperview];
                [view addSubview:viewLoop];
            }
        }
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

        return pdfPathWithFileName;
    }
}
```

This has been working fine for many months, but after updating to iOS 8, it has been behaving strangely.  There seems to be an imaginary breakpoint on the `UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()` line, as if a runtime error occurred, but there is no error message that pops up on screen or in the Console pane of the Debug area.  I have to hit the 'Continue Program Execution' button several times, and then the program continues to execute.

Afterwards, the file seems to be getting saved properly, but the `UIScrollView` on the screen gets shifted about half the screen width to the left, leaving the right half of the screen just empty space.

Does anyone know what changed in iOS 8 that is making me get these phantom breakpoints and strange UI behavior?